# More efficient switch statement in jQuery/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, optimization, switch-statement

I'm working on an app that uses a `switch` statement to provide custom animations depending on which link has been clicked to trigger the animation. It seems like a lot of code to get what I want, but I'm having a little trouble figuring out a better way to do it.

What happens is that when you click on a link, a `div` will open up to reveal hidden content and the other `divs` will slide to the side of the screen. Kinda like a custom accordian.

My `switch` statement looks like this - the `history` paramater is taken from the id of the clicked link. The divs are stored in an object called `rpsObject`.

```
switch( history ) {
    case "biography" :
        $("#" + rpsObject.boxId[1]).myAnimation();
        $("#" + rpsObject.boxId[2]).myAnimation({ top : 80 });
        $("#" + rpsObject.boxId[3]).myAnimation({ top: 160 });
        $("#" + rpsObject.boxId[4]).myAnimation({ top: 240 });
        $("#" + rpsObject.boxId[5]).fadeInCloseLink();
    break;
    case "blog" :
        $("#" + rpsObject.boxId[0]).myAnimation();
        $("#" + rpsObject.boxId[2]).myAnimation({ top : 80 });
        $("#" + rpsObject.boxId[3]).myAnimation({ top: 160 });
        $("#" + rpsObject.boxId[4]).myAnimation({ top: 240 });
        $("#" + rpsObject.boxId[5]).fadeInCloseLink();
    break;
    case "diary" :
        $("#" + rpsObject.boxId[0]).myAnimation();
        $("#" + rpsObject.boxId[1]).myAnimation({ top : 80 });
        $("#" + rpsObject.boxId[3]).myAnimation({ top: 160 });
        $("#" + rpsObject.boxId[4]).myAnimation({ top: 240 });
        $("#" + rpsObject.boxId[5]).fadeInCloseLink();
    break;
    case "reviews" :
        $("#" + rpsObject.boxId[0]).myAnimation();
        $("#" + rpsObject.boxId[1]).myAnimation({ top : 80 });
        $("#" + rpsObject.boxId[2]).myAnimation({ top: 160 });
        $("#" + rpsObject.boxId[4]).myAnimation({ top: 240 });
        $("#" + rpsObject.boxId[5]).fadeInCloseLink();
    break;
    case "images" :
        $("#" + rpsObject.boxId[0]).myAnimation();
        $("#" + rpsObject.boxId[1]).myAnimation({ top : 80 });
        $("#" + rpsObject.boxId[2]).myAnimation({ top: 160 });
        $("#" + rpsObject.boxId[3]).myAnimation({ top: 240 });
        $("#" + rpsObject.boxId[5]).fadeInCloseLink();
    break;
    case "contact" :
        $("#" + rpsObject.boxId[0]).myAnimation();
        $("#" + rpsObject.boxId[1]).myAnimation({ top : 80 });
        $("#" + rpsObject.boxId[2]).myAnimation({ top: 160 });
        $("#" + rpsObject.boxId[3]).myAnimation({ top: 240 });
        $("#" + rpsObject.boxId[4]).fadeInCloseLink();
    break;
}
```

Hopefully it should be pretty obvious what I'm doing here!

The functions `myAnimation()` and `fadeinCloseLink()` are custom functions. The latter must be performed on the last item of the object, which on complete trigger a custom animation for the selected `div`. The function `fadeinCloseLink()` does the following:

```
$.fn.fadeInCloseLink = function() {
    $(this).animate({ "left" : "640px", "top" : "320px", "height" : "80px" }, 300,
    function(){
        disFull.animate({ "opacity" : "toggle", "height" : "toggle" }, 500);
    });
}
```

Where `disFull` refers to the `div` that will be affected.

Hopefully this is clear enough to get my question across.

Comment: Hi T. J. - thanks for your comment. I appreciate the tip! I'll try and get my posts in order. Apologies for not being more organized!

Comment: Not a problem at all, happy to help. Best,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I came up with quickly

```
var historyItems = "biography,blog,diary,reviews,images,contact".split(",")
var currentSettings = [];
for (var i=0;i< historyItems.length; i++) {
  if (historyItems[i] != history) currentSettings.push(i)
}  
$("#" + rpsObject.boxId[currentSettings[0]]).myAnimation();
$("#" + rpsObject.boxId[currentSettings[1]]).myAnimation({ top : 80 });
$("#" + rpsObject.boxId[currentSettings[2]]).myAnimation({ top: 160 });
$("#" + rpsObject.boxId[currentSettings[3]]).myAnimation({ top: 240 });
$("#" + rpsObject.boxId[currentSettings[4]]).fadeInCloseLink();
```

Comment: Thank you mplungjan! Very elegant solution - this was exactly what was on the tip of my brain, but I just haven't enough experience to think this clearly! Works perfectly. Many thanks. I'd give you a +1 if I hadn't such a terrible reputation here!!

Answer (score 2):

You could refactor your code so that all the repeated portions go into a single function.

```
var myFunction = function(indexes){
        $("#" + rpsObject.boxId[indexes[0]]).myAnimation();
        $("#" + rpsObject.boxId[indexes[1]]).myAnimation({ top : 80 });
        $("#" + rpsObject.boxId[indexes[2]]).myAnimation({ top: 160 });
        $("#" + rpsObject.boxId[indexes[3]]).myAnimation({ top: 240 });
        $("#" + rpsObject.boxId[indexes[4]]).fadeInCloseLink();
    }

    switch( history ) {
    case "biography" :
       myFunction([1,2,3,4,5]);
    break;
    case "blog" :
        myFunction([0,2,3,4,5]);
    break;
    case "diary" :
        myFunction([0,1,3,4,5]);
    break;
    case "reviews" :
        myFunction([0,1,2,4,5]);
    break;
    case "images" :
        myFunction([0,1,2,3,5]);
    break;
    case "contact" :
        myFunction([0,1,2,3,4]);
    break;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm seeing it correctly, each case features this sequence of calls:

```
.myAnimation();
.myAnimation({ top : 80 });
.myAnimation({ top: 160 });
.myAnimation({ top: 240 });
.fadeInCloseLink();
```

...and it's just which elements those are called on that varies. So that's our first opportunity for refactoring.

The second is probably that we can do a lookup table:

```
var elementMap = {
    "biography": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    "blog":      [0, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    "diary":     [0, 1, 3, 4, 5],
    "reviews":   [0, 1, 2, 4, 5],
    "images":    [0, 1, 2, 3, 5],
    "contract":  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
};
```

and so:

```
var elements = elementMap[history];
rpsObject.boxId[elements[0]].myAnimation();
rpsObject.boxId[elements[1]].myAnimation({ top : 80 });
rpsObject.boxId[elements[2]].myAnimation({ top: 160 });
rpsObject.boxId[elements[3]].myAnimation({ top: 240 });
rpsObject.boxId[elements[4]].fadeInCloseLink();
```

Now, whether that's more maintainable is another question, but with your broader knowledge of the overall project, you may well be able to apply the techniques in a way which is both concise *and* maintainable.

Comment: Thanks also for your solution T.J! Slowly getting my head around JavaScript id made easier by having such a helpful, positive community. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Richard: No worries, good luck with it. Not touting (it's not monetized and not likely to be), but if you're new to JavaScript, you might want to take a look at my blog, particularly some of the [earlier](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008_02_01_archive.html) [entries](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008_03_01_archive.html). Years after using JavaScript as a play language, I started paying attention to how it actually worked, and wrote things up periodically.